# using sed to set a variable works on command line, but not bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have looked quite a bit for answers but I am not finding any suggestions that have worked so far.

on command line, this works:

```
$ myvar=$( cat -n /usr/share/dict/cracklib-small | grep $myrand | sed -e "s/$myrand//" )  
$ echo $myvar
$ commonness
```

however, inside a bash script the same exact lines just echoes out a blank line

notes - $myrand is a number, like 10340 generated with $RANDOM
cat prints out a dictionary with line numbers
grep grabs the line with $myrand in it  ; e.g. 10340  commonness
sed is intended to remove the $myrand part of the line and replace it with nothing. here is my sample script

```
#!/bin/bash
# prints out a random word
myrand=$RANDOM
export myrand
myword=$( cat -n /path/to/dict/cracklib-small | grep myrand | sed -e "s/$myrand//g" <<<"$myword" )
echo $myword
```

Comment: before use myrand print it and check maybe line with that number does not exist

Comment: BTW, that's a really bad way to get a random line. `grep 1` will match 1, 10, 11, 113, etc; `grep 101` will find 2101, 3101, 1013, etc. Or you could get a number that doesn't exist in the file and have no matches at all.

Comment: yes you are correct. just practicing. I'll find another way to get a random line - grep -w seems to work

Answer (score 2):

Your command line code is running:

```
grep $myrand
```

Your script is running:

```
grep myrand
```

These are not the same thing; the latter is looking for a word that contains "myrand" within it, not a random number.

---

By the way -- I'd suggest a different way to get a random line. If you have GNU coreutils, the `shuf` tool is built-to-purpose:

```
myword=$(shuf -n 1 /path/to/dict/cracklib-small)
```

Comment: and if you don't have shuf, this will work on any UNIX box: `awk 'BEGIN{srand()} {a[NR]=$0} END{print a[int(rand()*NR)+1]}' file`. If the file is huge you'd need a 2-pass approach rather than storing the entire file in memory, e.g. `awk -v nr="$(wc -l <file)" 'BEGIN{srand();tgt=int(rand()*nr)+1} NR==tgt{print;exit}' file`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
# prints out a random word
myrand=$RANDOM
export myrand
myword=$( cat -n /path/to/dict/cracklib-small | grep myrand | sed -e "s/$myrand//g" <<<"$myword" )
echo $myword
```

where is the $ sign in `grep myrand` ?

 **you must put in some work before posting it here.**

Comment: thanks. I spent a significant amount of time reading and trying alternatives and just didn't notice the error there. a mistake is not the same thing as laziness

Comment: well, that's understandable but you must know that as the number of posted questions increases, probability of a question getting timely answer decreases.
this is just an advice that am passing down, given to me by senior members of the community.